# SQL Server Compact Edition - Multiple Subscription issues

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a SQL server 2008 database successfully replicating to a Windows mobile database on a filter subscription. This works great.

However If my 2008 database goes down my mobile will not replicate anymore.
What i want to do is have a fail over SQL server which if subscription 1 fails to sync then i can call the second subscription on server 2 over another web address.

However i cannot add the addition subscription because there is already a subscription for the primary DB and as the tables are the same.

Any idea if this can be done and if not what is the best way to handle a fail over server for replication purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no provision for fail over servers through sync.  You would have to setup a SQL Server cluster and have the original sync happen against the cluster.

A database on another server can't be provisioned because the triggers and tombstone tables would be out of date.  I don't think they are replicated by default.